# Externalised pgfplots figure.eps gets rotated 180 degrees

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, externalize

I am externalizing some plots by pgfplots in .eps format by using these two sizes

case1:

```
width=0.55\textwidth
height=0.40\textwidth
```

case2:

```
width=0.6\textwidth
height=0.45\textwidth
```

which give a nice figure.eps in case1 but when I shift to the size in case2 it gives a 180 degree rotated figure.eps like here

[image]

If anyone has solved this problem plz give me a hint how to do it.

My text file is this

```
\documentclass[a4paper,9pt]{article}
%----------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{ amssymb }
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}
\usepgflibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize[prefix=FigEllBeh/]
\tikzset{external/export=true}
\tikzset{external/system call={latex \tikzexternalcheckshellescape -halt-on-error -interaction=batchmode -jobname "\image" "\texsource"; dvips -o "\image".eps "\image".dvi}}
%
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
width=0.6\textwidth,
height=0.45\textwidth,
xmin=0, xmax=1.01,
ymin=0, ymax=90,
ytick={0,30,60,90},
yticklabels={0,30,60,90},
%xtick={0,0.2,0.4,0.6,0.8,1},
%xticklabels={0,,0.4,,0.8,1},
extra x ticks={1},
extra y ticks={},
extra y tick labels={},
extra x tick labels={},
extra tick style={grid=major},
legend style={draw=none},
xlabel={$\lambda$},
ylabel={$\alpha\,\, {\rm in}\,\, [\degree]$}]
%
\addplot[black, mark=, line width=0.8pt] table[x index=0, y index=1, each nth point={4}]{../../DataFolder/EllBehData/Ws31.txt};
%
\addplot[black, mark=, line width=0.8pt, each nth point={4}] table[x index=0, y index=1]{../../DataFolder/EllBehData/Ws32.txt};
%
\node at (axis cs:0.7,75){$\rho=3$};
%
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: are you running `pdflatex` or `latex` on the above main document?

Comment: Which command/package does the conversion of the eps images into pdf?

Comment: @Herbert: the conversion is done via `\tikzset{external/system call={latex \tikzexternalcheckshellescape -halt-on-error -interaction=batchmode -jobname "\image" "\texsource"; dvips -o "\image".eps "\image".dvi}}`

Comment: I cannot see any conversion command from eps to pdf.

Comment: I am not sure what you exactly mean guys but the thing is that I am running this code using texmaker to generate my figure in EPS format and for this I just click on QUICK BUILD and then the figure.eps is generated but the problem with some specific sizes as I mentioned above... it gets rotated 90degrees and somtimes 180 degress but for other sizes it works normally.

PS: Conversion from eps to pdf is done when including my generated EPS to the main latex file by using \usepackage{epstopdf}